Running Multiline py files in Azure Maschine Learning Studio Notebooks
I'd like to know the best practice of running multiline shell commands in a ml notebook
Here is some pseudocode and how i would run IT in a notebook cell.
%%bash 
conda activate myenv &&

torchrun
    --standalone
    --nnodes=1
    --nproc-per-node=$NUM_TRAINERS
    YOUR_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py (--arg1 ... train script args...


I am activating the conda env because I noticed that the magic bash function alone doesn't use the correct environment.
Would it be better to use the command function from azure.ai.ml?
I find this way somehow error prone, even with activating conda and using the magic function.
Are there better alternatives?

The command job from azure.ai.ml is the better option, where you provide all the details to the compute cluster to run.
Whatever you are running in the notebook cell, it executes in the compute instance which is not a suitable compute for such workloads.
The compute instance has only a single node, while a compute cluster can have more nodes. A compute cluster can provide more memory and parallelism for the computation task.
So, you need to run the job in the compute cluster by submitting a command job.
When it comes to your environment, you don't need to change it as you did in the bash command. All you have to do is pass the environment object to the command job class, which contains the details of the environment you want.
Below is the sample.
custom_job_env = Environment(
    name=custom_env_name,
    description="Custom environment for Credit Card Defaults job",
    tags={"scikit-learn": "1.0.2"},
    conda_file=os.path.join(dependencies_dir, "conda.yaml"),
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04:latest",
)

Next, pass this to the command class.
job = command(
    ....
    command="python main.py --data ${{inputs.data}} --test_train_ratio ${{inputs.test_train_ratio}} --learning_rate ${{inputs.learning_rate}} --registered_model_name ${{inputs.registered_model_name}}",
    environment=custom_job_env,
    display_name="credit_default_prediction",
)

Refer to this Pytorch distributed training sample code.
And also, refer to more parameters you can configure for the command class here.
